# Consuming JMS messages by node.js

Tags: node.js, jms

Is there any npm module (or just a library) for node.js to consume messages from a JMS endpoint (tcp://jms.someadress.com:61616)

Answer (score 5):

If you are using RabbitMQ (or other [AMQP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Message_Queuing_Protocol) implementator) you can use [node-amqp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/amqp), a module to connect to messaging servers using AMQP protocol.

https://github.com/postwait/node-amqp.git

Answer (score 4):

Use Stomp protocol with [stomp-js](https://github.com/benjaminws/stomp-js) or [node-stomp-client](https://github.com/easternbloc/node-stomp-client). [ActiveMQ supports Stomp](http://activemq.apache.org/stomp.html) same as JBoss HornetQ. I assume you use ActiveMQ because port number matches to its default.

I guess that there should be also JMS-Stomp bridges which you can use with commercial JMS implementations.

Answer (score 0):

Note, [squaremo/amqp.node](https://github.com/squaremo/amqp.node/commits/master) seems to be more maintained nowadays than `node-amqp`, and is even recommended in the [RabbitMQ docs](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-javascript.html).

```
npm install amqplib
```

```js
var q = 'tasks';

var open = require('amqplib').connect('amqp://localhost');

// Publisher
open.then(function(conn) {
  return conn.createChannel();
}).then(function(ch) {
  return ch.assertQueue(q).then(function(ok) {
    return ch.sendToQueue(q, Buffer.from('something to do'));
  });
}).catch(console.warn);

// Consumer
open.then(function(conn) {
  return conn.createChannel();
}).then(function(ch) {
  return ch.assertQueue(q).then(function(ok) {
    return ch.consume(q, function(msg) {
      if (msg !== null) {
        console.log(msg.content.toString());
        ch.ack(msg);
      }
    });
  });
}).catch(console.warn);
```